# A cleaner way to pass many parameters into many functions in a script, without moving to object-oriented code structure?

Tags: matlab, function, parameters, code-organization

I am looking for some style/best practice advice. I often find myself writing scripts which need many (several tens of) parameters to be defined at the beginning. Then these parameters are used by many functions within the script. A minimum, simplified example might look something like the following:

```matlab
params.var1 = 1;
params.var2 = 10;
params.var3 = 100;
params.var4 = 1e3;

result1 = my_func1(params);
result2 = my_func2(params);
```

Now, I don't want to pass many inputs into every function, so am reluctant to do something like `result1 = my_func1(var1,var2,var3,var4,...)`. Therefore, I always find myself making each variable a field of a structure (e.g. `params`), and then passing this structure alone into each function, as above. The structure is not modified by the functions, only the parameters are used for further calculations.

One of the functions might look like this then:

```matlab
function result = my_func1(params)

var1 = params.var1;
var2 = params.var2;
var3 = params.var3;
var4 = params.var4;

result = var1.^2 + var2.^2 -var3.^3 + var4;

end
```

Now, because I don't want to refer to each variable within the function as `params.var1`, etc. (in the interest of keeping the expression for `result` as clear as possible), I first do all this unpacking at the beginning using `var1 = params.var1`.

I suppose the best thing to be doing in situations like this might be to use classes (because I have some data and also want to perform functions on that data). Are there any better ways for me to be doing this kind of thing without moving fully to object-oriented code?

Comment: Global variables ?

Comment: That would work, but I was always taught to be very careful using globals, and if you find you need to use them then you might consider that your code is not organised in the best way to start with.

Comment: I don't live on dogmas. In 99% of the cases, global variables are harmless.

Comment: I know, I was just thinking this may be one of those situations where I have set up the problem incorrectly in the first place, and globals would be like putting a band aid over it.

Comment: You can ask yourself "given my application, is there a reason that these variables could exist in multiple instances", and "is there a danger that a function call modifying these variables unexpectedly will wreak havoc" ?

Comment: If MATLAB had a way of declaring constant global variables, I’d agree with @Yves, but given the possibility that one of them is changed accidentally somewhere, causing a very hard to discover bug, I’d avoid globals. Constant functions is MATLAB’s way of doing global constants, they’re a good solution. Passing a struct around is also a very good solution. Don’t overthink it! If you call the struct `p` inside your function you won’t need to do the unpacking.

Comment: @CrisLuengo when you say "constant functions", you mean exactly as in the answer from rahnema1 below? As I commented there, it feels a little cumbersome to me to edit the parameters within all those functions.

Comment: Yes, constant functions as in rahnema1's solution. If you need your uses to modify parameters, that's not viable, I agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply leave the unpacking out. Call the `struct params` something shorter inside the function, to keep clutter to a minimum:

```
function result = my_func1(p)
result = p.var1.^2 + p.var2.^2 - p.var3.^3 + p.var4;
end
```

I would keep calling it `params` elsewhere, so you don’t have to deal with cryptic names.

Comment: I think this method is the best compromise, and just live with the dot notation inside the function expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can define constant functions:

```
function out = var1
  out = 1; 
end
function out = var2
  out = 10; 
end

function result = my_func1
  result = var1.^2 + var2.^2;
end
```

Based on your actual application you may pass array of numbers:

```
var = [var1 var2 var3 var4]; 
my_func1(var);
```

`my_func1(var1,var2,var3,var4,...)` in my opinion is preferred over passing struct.

Comment: Thanks, I did not consider using a constant function. However, although it does make the content of my_func1() simpler (because I don't have to do the unpacking inside the function), it is quite messy to have all the parameters listed inside their own individual functions.

Comment: The second method (passing an array) also isn't any better than the structure method, because inside the function my_func1() I will still have to unpack using var1 = var(1).

Comment: The final suggestion will become extremely cumbersome with tens of variables.

Comment: Note that MATLAB uses constant functions like `pi`. So it can be considered a standard way of doing such.

Comment: Yes I have no problem with the idea of a constant function itself. The problem is more that there seems to now be a lot of distracting clutter around each variable. These variables will be something that will be changed by the user, so it is less elegant for them to have to change values inside functions, rather than a simple list of parameters in my original example. Do you see what I mean? I suppose we have moved the clutter from one place to another with this approach.

Comment: I the user wants to change the variable there is no difference between changing a variable inside a function vs changing it inside the script. A minimal example may clarify.

Comment: For example, if I have 30 parameters to define, then your method means that instead of 30 lines of the code at the beginning of the script I would have 90 lines of code.

Comment: I prefer 90 lines of 30 functions over passing 30 parameters to each functions.

Comment: Yes, me too. Which is why I disagree with your opinion that passing all the variables inline "is preferred over passing struct". I think the struct gets around this problem.

Comment: I suggest that you benchmark/test different methods and provide an answer comparing timings of each (using your actual function). It will be useful for me and other users too.

Comment: It's nothing to do with timing though - I have no requirements on speed at all. The problem is that I feel like at the moment I am using more code (simply in terms of number of characters) to achieve what I want. But it feels like lots of those characters are repeated, and in these situations there is usually a better way of doing things in my experience.

Comment: Moreover when using struct you need extra 30 lines for each function  to unpack the struct.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's the main problem. If there was a simple solution to that then I would be happy with the approach.